# Check if local time is not consistent with timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Is there any way to detect in javascript that the user local time set in the OS is different than the official time of the OS timezone? For example, I'm in UTC+01:00 and it's 7:20 AM now according to the set timezone. Suppose I change manually my system time to be 9:20 AM without changing the timezone - it's now different than the official UTC+1 time. Is there any way to detect such inconsistency?

Comment: Javascript Date objects don't know anything about time zones, they are UTC at heart, so just compare the UTC date and time with the same from an accurate source, allowing some time for network latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to npm to compile your JavaScript file, you can obtain these 2 libraries to get your actual timezone:

First obtain your IP address with this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-ip

Then, obtain your location (latitude, longitude) with this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/satelize

And finally compare you computer time (new Date()) time with the one you obtain from a time service like google maps, check out the following tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/local-time-google-time-zone-api.shtml